# Jquery Selector fails after setContent called on info window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asynchronous, infowindow

I have a google maps info window that I open on a map, directly after which I want to bind event listeners to parts of the html in the info window.  I do this with JQuery.  The code goes something like:

```
myInfoWindow.open(map);
$('#someIdInInfoWindow').bind({
    click: function() { foo1(); },
    mouseenter: function() { foo2(); }
});
```

Unfortunately, I think Google makes most of their libraries asynchronous, so the content of the info window is not actually set until after the JQuery selector has been called.

How can I fix this so the event handlers are properly set?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait for the domready-event of the infoWindow before you add the listeners, at this time the HTML-element representing the infowindow has been attached to the document and it's contents are accessible :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myInfoWindow,'domready',function(){
  $('#someIdInInfoWindow').bind({
    click: function() { foo1(); },
    mouseenter: function() { foo2(); }
 });
});
```

This applies when the content of the infoWindow is set via a string, when you assign it via a node you may also add the listeners directly to the particular element when you create it:

```
    var content = $('<div/>')
                    .append($('<div/>',{id:'someIdInInfoWindow'})
                              .text('some text')
                              .click(foo1)
                              .mouseenter(foo2));
    myInfoWindow.setContent(content[0]);
    myInfoWindow.open(map);
```

Comment: +1 for solution. I'll try it and all works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/vfLovh23/2/